# Как в yii2 вынести вендора вне папки vendors и сделать частью проекта

Tags: php, yii2, composer, autoload

Суть в том, что проект тесно завязан на одном вендоре, не выходит stable релизов. Нужно подключить данный компонент c этой папки(пример: app/название_вендора), сохранив старый namespace.Компонент подключается в config/web, в секции modules. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Покажу на примере модуля `kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker`. Вынесем этот модуль из папки `vendor` в папку `common/modules`.

**1)** Удаляем строку из секции `require` в `composer.json` которая отвечает за модуль, который мы выносим. То есть, в нашем примере, удаляем строку `"kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev",`

**2)** Открываем файл `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` и находим внутри него строку, отвечающую за выносимый модуль (в нашем примере эта строка - `'kartik\\date\\' => array($vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker'),`).

**3)** Создаём внутри `composer.json` на одном уровне с секциями `require` и `require-dev`новую секцию `autoload` (если её нет). Внутри этой секции создаём ещё одну секцию `psr-4` и уже внутрь неё помещаем только что найденную строку из файла `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` с небольшими изменениями (нужно заменить `$vendorDir` на путь до папки где будет располагаться модуль и некоторые другие изменения).

Пример получившейся секции:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "kartik\\date\\": "common/modules/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker"
    }
}
```

**4)** Открываем файл `vendor/yiisoft/extensions.php` и находим в нём блок с нашим модулем. В нашем случае блок выглядит так:

```
'kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker',
    'version' => '9999999-dev',
    'alias' => 
    array (
      '@kartik/date' => $vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker',
    ),
  ),
```

**5)** Открываем файл конфигурации (`common/config/main.php` или `config/web.php`). Внутрь файла на одном уровне с `components` и `modules` создаём новую секцию `extensions` и присоединяем внутри только что найденный блок массива (с небольшим изменением, схожим с шагом **3**, то есть заменяем `$vendorDir` на путь до папки где будет располагаться модуль) к тому же файлу из которого мы его скопировали (так сразу слёту возможно непонятен этот шаг, но с опытом вынесения модулей придёт понимание).

Пример получившейся секции:

```
'extensions' => yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require( dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/yiisoft/extensions.php'),
    'kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker' => 
    array (
        'name' => 'kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker',
        'version' => '9999999-dev',
        'alias' => 
        array (
            '@kartik/date' => 'common/modules/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker',
        ),
    ),
),
```

**6)** Делаем `composer update` и наслаждаемся результатом. Теперь этот модуль находится в нашем проекте, и мы можем изменять его код не волнуясь за то, что изменения слетят после обновления компосера.

С виду всё сложно, но на деле это занимает 2 минуты. Удачи.

Comment: А зависимости пакета нужно добавлять в composer.json? И зачем добавлять пакет в секцию `extensions`?